# Disable push notification sound whenever I want

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to disable the push notification sound - whenever the alert comes in.

Currently I am using a blank sound file to do this, but is there a way to disable the sound.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to play sounds, you can register for remote notifications again for only alert notification type. If you want the sound should not be played on receiving the alert notification, you should not be sending the sound value in the notification payload sent from the notification server.

Comment: {
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello",
    }
} would only display the alert and not play the sound.

Answer (score 1):

You specify a bitmask of notification types when you register for notifications. If you don't want a sound to be played when notifications come in, remove `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` from that bitmask:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the preferences application and select "Notifications", select your app and turn off the sound.

Comment: I do think he want's to know how to do it on the code, otherwise it doesn't make sense to make this kind of question here.

Comment: yeah i want to do this from code, please help is someone know this, how to do.

Comment: @Saad Op wants to perform it programatically, not the user side.